# Django Forms: Получение полей во view через точку

Tags: python, django

Является ли правильным получение поля формы во view через точку или нужно обращаться к cleaned_data?

```
if form.is_valid():
    user = request.user
    avatar = form.avatar
    # or avatar = form.cleaned_data['avatar']
```

Comment: Можно ещё как альтернативу брать данные из `request.POST/GET.get('field',None)`. По сути то же самое, но в данном контексте clened_data логичней

Answer (score 0):

Нет, не является, так как form.avatar вернёт объект django.forms.widgets..., а не заполненный input формы

Answer (score 0):

а еще можно посмотреть api форм

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data